# Can't access a web service outside my domain in ajax with php

Tags: php, ajax, cross-domain

I know that I can bypass the same domain policy by creating an intermediary file call like this:

```
$.getJSON('service_facade.php', function(data) {

        options.series = data;
    // Create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

the service_facade.php contents looks like this in php:

```
print_r($_GET["http://myservice.com/parameters"]);
```

The problem is that the chart I am accessing is not rendering. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax cross domain question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1974452/ajax-cross-domain-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way around the same-origen policy is to create a php file or the like which does the service interaction for you.  It is not bound to the policy like AJAX is.  Once you invoke the facade php file that does the remote domain call and returns data, you can access this data via php.

Answer (score 2):

That's because of the same-origin policy which restricts Ajax requests to the same domain the page came from. This means you can't access an Ajax API outside of your domain.

There's a spec out there called [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/) which would work around this but I don't know of this being implemented yet.